# Removal of Media Gallery pictures

Tags: posts, uploads, media

When I delete pictures from the media gallery ,does it delete the photos from the post that has been published?

Answer (score 0):

If those images have been inserted in your posts, deleting them from the Media Library will cause blank spaces with a broken image icon to appear in your posts.

If you need/want to add alt text or change image file names, etc., better to do so directly in the Media Library than to delete existing images and then upload them again. If you do this, you will have to reinsert all the images in your posts again!